# Passing DataGridComboBoxColumn value to a ObjectDataProvider's MethodParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have two DataGridComboBoxColumns (technically DataGridTemplateColumns) in a DataGrid. I'm using MVVM.

The first column's ItemsSource is bound to a static resource -- no problem there.

The second column's ItemsSource is dependent on the value chosen by the first column. The first column's value (SelectedValue) is passed to an ObjectDataProvider as a MethodParameter. The ObjectDataProvider is the second column's ItemsSource.

The problem with using the first column's SelectedValue as ObjectDataProvider's MethodParameter is when I insert a second row in the DataGrid. If the second row uses a different value in column 1 than it did in the first row's column 1, it clears the first row's column 2 value (as the new SelectedValue changes the allowable list of items to choose from, provided by the ObjectDataProvider).

I'd really like to pass in the first column's Text value to the ObjectDataProvider as its MethodParameter, but how can I do so when the first column's Text value is already bound to update my model?

Here's excerpts of my problem XAML:

```
<!--
My ObjectDataProvider. It returns a collection of strings for the user to choose from via the second DataGridTemplateColumn.
The first DataGridTemplateColumn feeds ObjectDataProvider a MethodParameter. 

The method is simple. It looks like:
    public List<String> ProductLineCategoryList_CategoryCodes(string productLineCode)
    {
        // return a list of strings based from an object collection, filtered by the passed in argument.
    }
-->

<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="categoryCodes" ObjectType="{x:Type e:ItemsProvider}" MethodName="ProductLineCategoryList_CategoryCodes">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:StaticExtension Member="sys:String.Empty"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<!-- 
This DataGridComboBoxColumn lets the user choose a ProductLineCode.
Its SelectedValue provides a string value for the ObjectDataProvider's MethodParameter.
The ObjectDataProvider is used as the ItemsSource for the DataGridComboBoxColumn
below this one.
The problem with using SelectedValue to feed ObjectDataProvider a MethodParameter, when
a second row is added to my DataGrid and the second row uses a different ProductLineCode than
the first row, it clears the first row's ProductLineCategoryCode value.
-->
<DataGridTemplateColumn 
    Header="Product Line"
    ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ProductLineCode}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox
                IsEditable="True"
                ItemsSource="{x:Static e:ItemsProvider.ProductLineCategoryList_ProductLineCodeList}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryCodes}, 
                                Path=MethodParameters[0], BindsDirectlyToSource=True, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Text="{Binding ProductLineCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>                                               
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductLineCode}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>              
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<!-- 
This DataGridComboBoxColumn uses the ObjectDataProvider for its ItemsSource.
ItemsSource s/b limited by the selection made from the above DataGridComboBoxColumn.
-->
<DataGridTemplateColumn 
    Header="Product Line Cat"
    ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ProductLineCategoryCode}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox 
                IsEditable="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryCodes}}"
                Text="{Binding ProductLineCategoryCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>                                               
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductLineCategoryCode}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>              
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I've referenced the net for help, but I can't find a solution that works for me. I only need to pass in a string, not an object (though I guess I could change my ObjectDataProvider's method to accept an object and [then this might work](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/02/supplying-an-object-reference-in-the-constructorparameters-collection-of-an-objectdataprovider/)). This [MSDN solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.methodparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) would work great if this weren't a DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you're trying to do too many things in the XAML.

You'd better leverage your VM.

Here is an example that mimics your model and situation:

The business/VM entity:

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string[]> catalog = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
    {
        { "Fruit", new[]{ "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry" } },
        { "Vegatable", new[]{ "Amaranth", "Broccolini", "Celery" } }
    };

    public static IDictionary<string, string[]> Catalog { get { return catalog; } }

    private string productLineCategoryCode;
    public string ProductLineCategoryCode
    {
        get { return productLineCategoryCode; }
        set
        {
            if (value != productLineCategoryCode)
            {
                productLineCategoryCode = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductLineCategoryCode"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductLineCodes"));
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ProductLineCodes
    {
        get
        {
            return Catalog[ProductLineCategoryCode];
        }
    }

    private string productLineCode;
    public string ProductLineCode
    {
        get { return productLineCode; }
        set
        {
            if (value != productLineCode)
            {
                productLineCode = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductLineCode"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

The `ProductLineCodes` is the list of available codes for a given category, you simply bind to it.

So when the user changes the category we notify that both it and the list of available codes have changed.

The view:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product Line Cat"
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ProductLineCategoryCode}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(local:Product.Catalog).Keys}"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding ProductLineCategoryCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductLineCategoryCode}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product Line" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ProductLineCode}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ProductLineCodes}"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding ProductLineCode,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">                                
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductLineCode}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I can imagine another variant using an `IValueConverter` but I hope this one will be good enough for your use-case...

Comment: This works. Thanks, @Pragmateek! I was trying hard to keep data access code out of my models. Now I understand if I want to do that I need to wrap each model in a VM that provides the data access logic. For now, I simply plugged in a public string[] ProductLineCategoryCodes property into my model per your suggestion. I'll later refactor (create lots more VMs which are then exposed to the main VM for my View) to extract the data access code from my model. Thanks for getting me out of a rut! BTW, great profile. I would've learned programming at two but I was busy reverse engineering time.

Comment: @DavidAlanCondit Glad it works. Yes the VM is there to adapt your model to ease consumption from the view. You don't have to wrap everything in VMs, and finding the right balance is some of the hard parts of WPF design but the more you do it the less time it takes.

Comment: Agreed. I did a small refactor: I have a static "ItemsProvider" class which is loaded with list properties for my many models (Products, Locations, Divisions, ProductLineCategories, etc) - it fills these lists w/ values from the database. The models that need these lists query ItemsProvider, rather than query the db itself. It's probably not perfect but it's a step in the right directly. FYI for anyone interested.

Comment: What you do is more than a step in the right direction. :) You've just done a basic implementation of the **repository pattern** so it's just fine. Have a look at this pattern to help decouple your data-layer from the rest of your application.